# How to keep track of encryption keys for individual files in a web service?

Tags: file, encryption, key, tracking

I'm working on adding the option to encrypt uploaded files on my website by giving each file a "password", but I'm not sure of the best way to keep track of the encryption keys for each individual file. For example, when retrieving the file if the user enters the wrong password I'm pretty sure it'll download the file, but it won't be unencrypted properly. Is it best to store the hashed & salted passwords for each file in a database and match up there first? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the encryption keys as hashed (and salted) values, there is no way to retrieve the original encryption key.  If you hash something (with a strong hashing algorithm), you cannot get the original back.

The best mechanism depends on the operating environment (OS, plus potentially other software installed), and on the requirements.

Depending on the specific requirements, it may be best *not* to store the encryption key at all.  The point is that the *user* wants to protect data and the *user* knows the key.  If it is possible to perform the encryption on the client side, the key would never have to traverse the network at all (e.g. encrypt in JavaScript).  If the encryption must happen on the server,  ensure the key is sent via an https connection, use it in memory to encrypt the file, and remove from memory (if your language supports immediately removing something from memory... e.g. in C# use a SecureString).

If you *must* keep the encryption key (which is a security issue on several levels), you will have to state more information about the operating environment.

Comment: Well I understand that I will never be able to retrieve the original key, and sorry I don't know much about encryption (I'm just starting to learn), but I was under the impression that every time they enter their password and it gets hashed and salted the end result will always be the same? So if I confirm the hashed and salted version of whatever they entered is the same as what's in the DB then I know they're entering the right password so I can go ahead with the decryption?

Comment: The central point is *so I can go ahead with the decryption*.  Decryption based on *what*?  You *can* use a single key on the server for everyone.  However, that allows anyone with access to that key to decrypt *everyone's* data.  It is more secure to allow each user to create and manage their own key.  At the end of the day, it depends on what your needs are.  If you just want to authenticate the person and use your own key for encryption/decryption, storing the salted hash is sufficient.  You should have a different salt per user, also stored in the DB.

Comment: Okay great! That gives me a good place to start. Thanks a ton.